# How to autogenerate id if there is no id in document with elasticjs v5.0

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to add documents, according to elastic search documents, we can add document, even if we dont provide id... [See Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html)

I am trying to add a document even if it doesnt have any ID. in elastic search, how can i do that?
My current code looks like this

```
var params = _.defaults({}, {
    index: index,
    type: type, //'customer'
    id: data.id || null,
    body: data
})
debug(params)
return this.client.create(params);
```

The above code gives this error

> {
>     "error": "Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index, type, id"
>   }

Any hint would help, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `index` and `type` have non-null values?

Comment: What happens if you pass your options directly to the create call, without resorting to using underscore's `defaults` function?

Comment: yes, i am sure, because when i provide `id` it creates the document, also i am logging the input as you can see `debug` function

Comment: this is what i have in parameter.
`{ index: 'index', type: 'mytype', body: { id: '1', age: 20, name: 'Faizan', tags: [ 'faizan', 'user' ] } }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `create` call you MUST provide an id.

If you are not sure if an ID will be present in your `data` , then you can use the [`client.index()` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-4.html#api-index-2-4) instead. using that function, ES will auto-generate an ID if none is provided.